# How do to do an if statement in a stored procedure

Tags: mysql

Basically, i'm going to be passing my parameter `SystemFeedbackidParam` if SystemFeedbackidParam is not null, do one thing, if it is, then do the seperate thing.  I can do this in SQL but the way to do this is mysql is eluding me.

Thanks!

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `_Insert_FeedBack`(
   FeedbackTypeParam       varchar(20),
   FeedbackSubjectParam    varchar(200),
   FeedbackTextParam       text,
   FeedbackHTMLParam       longtext,
   SubmittedByParam        varchar(20),
   SubmittedDateParam      datetime,
   SystemFeedbackidParam int)
   BEGIN
      IF (SystemFeedbackidParam IS NOT NULL)
      THEN
--/*Insert Child Record into tblfeedbackitems */
         INSERT INTO tblfeedbackitems(SystemFeedbackId,
                                      FeedbackType,
                                      FeedbackText,
                                      FeedbackHTML,
                                      SubmittedBy,
                                      SubmittedDate)
         VALUES (SystemFeedbackidParm,
                 FeedbackTypeParam            
                                  ,
                 FeedbackTextParam          
                                  ,
                 FeedbackHTMLParam          
                                  ,
                 SubmittedByParam           
                                 ,
                 SubmittedDateParam         
                                   );
      ELSE
 --/*Insert Parent Record into tblFeedback */

         INSERT INTO tblfeedback(
                                 FeedbackType,
                                 FeedbackSubject,
                                 FeedbackStatus)
         VALUES (
                 FeedbackTypeParam,
                 FeedbackSubjectParam,
                 'Open');

--/*Insert Child Record into tblFeedback */
         INSERT INTO tblfeedbackitems(SystemFeedbackId,
                                      FeedbackType,
                                      FeedbackText,
                                      FeedbackHTML,
                                      SubmittedBy,
                                      SubmittedDate)
         VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),
                 FeedbackTypeParam            
                                  ,
                 FeedbackTextParam          
                                  ,
                 FeedbackHTMLParam          
                                  ,
                 SubmittedByParam           
                                 ,
                 SubmittedDateParam         
                                   );
      END
```

Comment: I think you `IF` is OK. Do you have a `DELIMITER` statement before the procedure?

Comment: @Barmar no - but i'm really really cautious about my stored procedures because mysqldump becomes really really finicky with the dumps

Comment: Your comment syntax is not correct. Comments are either from `-- ` to the end of the line, or between `/*` and `*/`, you don't need both. When you use the `--` prefix, it has to have a space after it.

Comment: You need a `DELIMITER` statement. Otherwise, the `;` between the statements will terminate the procedure definition.

Comment: @Barmar okay fine, i can remove all that it still doesnt answer the original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems here:

- Comments start with --(space) - yours are missing the space
- Delimiters. Change the delimiter at the top so that the semi-colons don't terminate your procedure. Change it back at the bottom
- You've opened and IF statement but not closed it
- You've opened a BEGIN but not terminated the closing END

Try this:

```
Delimiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `_Insert_FeedBack`(
   FeedbackTypeParam       varchar(20),
   FeedbackSubjectParam    varchar(200),
   FeedbackTextParam       text,
   FeedbackHTMLParam       longtext,
   SubmittedByParam        varchar(20),
   SubmittedDateParam      datetime,
   SystemFeedbackidParam int)
   BEGIN
      IF (SystemFeedbackidParam IS NOT NULL)
      THEN
-- /*Insert Child Record into tblfeedbackitems */
         INSERT INTO tblfeedbackitems(SystemFeedbackId,
                                      FeedbackType,
                                      FeedbackText,
                                      FeedbackHTML,
                                      SubmittedBy,
                                      SubmittedDate)
         VALUES (SystemFeedbackidParm,
                 FeedbackTypeParam            
                                  ,
                 FeedbackTextParam          
                                  ,
                 FeedbackHTMLParam          
                                  ,
                 SubmittedByParam           
                                 ,
                 SubmittedDateParam         
                                   );
      ELSE
 -- /*Insert Parent Record into tblFeedback */

         INSERT INTO tblfeedback(
                                 FeedbackType,
                                 FeedbackSubject,
                                 FeedbackStatus)
         VALUES (
                 FeedbackTypeParam,
                 FeedbackSubjectParam,
                 'Open');

-- /*Insert Child Record into tblFeedback */
         INSERT INTO tblfeedbackitems(SystemFeedbackId,
                                      FeedbackType,
                                      FeedbackText,
                                      FeedbackHTML,
                                      SubmittedBy,
                                      SubmittedDate)
         VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),
                 FeedbackTypeParam            
                                  ,
                 FeedbackTextParam          
                                  ,
                 FeedbackHTMLParam          
                                  ,
                 SubmittedByParam           
                                 ,
                 SubmittedDateParam         
                                   );
      END IF; 
END $$
Delimiter ;
```

Note: I've fixed your syntax errors. I have no idea whether your code will actually work.

Answer (score 0):

check the documentation of mysql on this site http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html
there you can find all the info, but basically is like this

```
IF NOT SystemFeedbackidParam THEN
......
 END IF;
```

also you can use the else statement.

Comment: is very simple you can do like this: `IF SystemFeedbackidParam IS NOT NULL THEN here is your code ELSE the other code END IF;` i think this will work for you